# Trying to install lxml for python, "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2."

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install lxml for python using pip. I have tried `sudo pip install lxml` and `sudo pip install lxml` both of these give the error:

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

No idea what is going on here. Who is Xcode getting involved? Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you used `xcodebuild -license` to accept the Xcode licence?  Without this clang/clang++ will not run.  Or have you even installed the command line tools?

Comment: Why do I have to accept an Xcode licence for a Python module? (Just accepted it now). I don't have command line tools installed. Do you mean the Xcode command line tools?

Comment: While lxml is a "python module", it is not written purely in python.  It needs to be compiled ... so you need a c-compiler ... so you probably want the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Got it. Works now. thanks for your help.